# How to open Java fxml screen inside other screen on click of button

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

I have three screens in fxml .first screen is login screen.After authentication ,on clicking on login button.user enters in second screen.I have done it.Now on screen 2, there is a button called authentication.on clicking this button,third screen is opened inside second screen.How can i achieve it i.e how can i open 3rd screen inside 2nd screen on click of button.plz suggest some way to do this in javafx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you look at this question: [Multiple FXML with Controllers, share object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166786/multiple-fxml-with-controllers-share-object) I use this in my current application :)