# How to fill data in TableView in screen2 from screen1

Tags: java, controller, javafx, tableview

```
public class Screen1DocumentController implements Initializable {

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

    @FXML public void handleLogin() throws IOException{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screen2Document.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @FXML Button btnLogin;


}
```

Below **Screen2DocumentController.java**:

```
public class Screen2DocumentController implements Initializable {

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        ReportDetails r;
        r = new ReportDetails("pavan");
        rptDtls.add(r);
        rptDtls.add(new ReportDetails("Viajy"));
        rptDtls.add(new ReportDetails("sharat"));
        rptDtls.add(new ReportDetails("sandeep"));
        rptDtls.add(new ReportDetails("bhaskar"));
        rptDtls.add(new ReportDetails("nokal"));

    }    

    private ObservableList<ReportDetails> rptDtls =  FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @FXML TableView tblData;
    @FXML TableColumn<ReportDetails,String> tblCData;
}
```

When I click on the login button I am getting run time errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Some stack trace will be helpful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a reference of controller1 to controller2 by

```
    Screen2DocumentController controller2 = (Screen2DocumentController)fxmlloader.getController();
```

add variable to Screen2DocumentController

```
private Screen1DocumentController controller1;
```

add a method to Screen2DocumentController

```
public void setScreen1DocumentController(Screen1DocumentController controller){this.contoller1 = controller; }
```

now you can call method in your handlelogin method

`((Screen2DocumentController)fxmlloader.getController()).setScreen1DocumentController(this);`

now you have a reference of controller1 in controller2.

If you now add a method to Screen1DocumentController sayHello

```
public void sayHello(String name){ System.out.println("Hello "+name);}
```

you could call it from Screen2DocumentController by using

```
controller1.sayHello("pavankumar");
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

First put your FXMLLoader call into a try/catch to get detailled information
about the error.I guess that your path to Screen2Document.fxml is not correct or the import statement for ReportDetails is missing?

Comment: now i am able to send data from Screen1DocumentController to Screen2DocumentController i read this post "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166786/multiple-fxml-with-controllers-share-object/" this is fine for sending data from controller1 to subcontroller.But i want data to be sent from subcontroller to controller1.?