# Application context in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am looking for Context class in javaFx.Is there any ? as we do have in android.
Basically I have one class for network call get and I want to pass a refernence in a constructor from any other Controller.In android its easy Context can take care of it but how to do it in javaFx desktop application.

Comment: Could you reword the second sentence? As someone unfamiliar with Android's Context, it's a little unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please post the code as to what you have tried, and where it is failing.  There are many different ways to accomplish this.  There is no global context class in JavaFX - however you can solve this with patterns.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166786/multiple-fxml-with-controllers-share-object is helpful for you.