# Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML

Tags: javafx, parameters, dependency-injection, parameter-passing, fxml

How can I pass parameters to a secondary window in javafx? Is there a way to communicate with the corresponding controller?

For example:
The user chooses a customer from a `TableView` and a new window is opened, showing the customer's info.

```
Stage newStage = new Stage();
try 
{
    AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(HectorGestion.class.getResource(fxmlResource));
    Scene scene = new Scene(page);
    newStage.setScene(scene);
    newStage.setTitle(windowTitle);
    newStage.setResizable(isResizable);
    if(showRightAway) 
    {
        newStage.show();
    }
}
```

`newStage` would be the new window. The problem is, I can't find a way to tell the controller where to look for the customer's info (by passing the id as parameter).

Any ideas?

Comment: Check to see if this works too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370183/passing-parameters-to-a-controller-when-loading-an-fxml/14432578#14432578

Comment: @Alvaro: did you get your solution? can you pass parameter? from one controller to another controller file?

Comment: Yes. jewelsea gave a book-level explanation. That's why I accepted his answer

Answer (score 307, accepted):

**Using MVC**

Most of this answer focuses on a direct call to pass a parameter from a calling class to the controller.

If instead, you want to decouple the caller and controller and use a more general architecture involving a model class with settable and listenable properties to achieve inter-controller communication, see the following basic overview:

- [Applying MVC With JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx)

**Recommended Approach**

This answer enumerates different mechanisms for passing parameters to FXML controllers.

For small applications I highly recommend passing parameters directly from the caller to the controller - it's simple, straightforward and requires no extra frameworks.

For larger, more complicated applications, it would be worthwhile investigating if you want to use [Dependency Injection](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) or [Event Bus](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained) mechanisms within your application.

**Passing Parameters Directly From the Caller to the Controller**

Pass custom data to an FXML controller by retrieving the controller from the FXML loader instance and calling a method on the controller to initialize it with the required data values.

Something like the following code:

```
public Stage showCustomerDialog(Customer customer) {
  FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
    getClass().getResource(
      "customerDialog.fxml"
    )
  );

  Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
  stage.setScene(
    new Scene(loader.load())
  );

  CustomerDialogController controller = loader.getController();
  controller.initData(customer);

  stage.show();

  return stage;
}

...

class CustomerDialogController {
  @FXML private Label customerName;
  void initialize() {}
  void initData(Customer customer) {
    customerName.setText(customer.getName());
  }
}
```

A new FXMLLoader is constructed as shown in the sample code i.e. `new FXMLLoader(location)`.  The location is a URL and you can generate such a URL from an FXML resource by:

```
new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
```

*Be careful NOT to use a static load function on the FXMLLoader, or you will not be able to get your controller from your loader instance.*

FXMLLoader instances themselves never know anything about domain objects.  You do not directly pass application specific domain objects into the FXMLLoader constructor, instead you:

1. Construct an FXMLLoader based upon fxml markup at a specified location
2. Get a controller from the FXMLLoader instance.
3. Invoke methods on the retrieved controller to provide the controller with references to the domain objects.

This blog (by another writer) provides an alternate, but similar, [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20160612045146/http://ed4becky.net/homepage/javafx-from-the-trenches-singleton-controllers/).

**Setting a Controller on the FXMLLoader**

```
CustomerDialogController dialogController = 
    new CustomerDialogController(param1, param2);

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
    getClass().getResource(
        "customerDialog.fxml"
    )
);
loader.setController(dialogController);

Pane mainPane = loader.load();
```

You can construct a new controller in code, passing any parameters you want from your caller into the controller constructor.  Once you have constructed a controller, you can set it on an FXMLLoader instance *before* you invoke the `load()` *instance* method.

*To set a controller on a loader (in JavaFX 2.x) you CANNOT also define a `fx:controller` attribute in your fxml file.*

Due to the limitation on the `fx:controller` definition in FXML, I personally prefer getting the controller from the FXMLLoader rather than setting the controller into the FXMLLoader.

**Having the Controller Retrieve Parameters from an External Static Method**

This method is exemplified by Sergey's answer to [Javafx 2.0 How-to Application.getParameters() in a Controller.java file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10136403/1155209).

**Use Dependency Injection**

FXMLLoader supports dependency injection systems like Guice, Spring or Java EE CDI by allowing you to set a custom controller factory on the FXMLLoader.  This provides a callback that you can use to create the controller instance with dependent values injected by the respective dependency injection system.

An example of JavaFX application and controller dependency injection with Spring is provided in the answer to:

- [Adding Spring Dependency Injection in JavaFX (JPA Repo, Service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887944/adding-spring-dependency-injection-in-javafx-jpa-repo-service)

A really nice, clean dependency injection approach is exemplified by the [afterburner.fx framework](https://github.com/AdamBien/afterburner.fx) with a sample [air-hacks application](https://github.com/AdamBien/airhacks-control) that uses it.  afterburner.fx relies on JEE6 [javax.inject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/package-summary.html) to perform the dependency injection.

**Use an Event Bus**

Greg Brown, the original FXML specification creator and implementor, often suggests considering use of an event bus, such as the Guava [EventBus](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained), for communication between FXML instantiated controllers and other application logic.

> The EventBus is a simple but powerful publish/subscribe API with annotations that allows POJOs to communicate with each other anywhere in a JVM without having to refer to each other.

**Follow-up Q&A**

> on first method, why do you return Stage? The method can be void as well because you already giving the command show(); just before return stage;. How do you plan usage by returning the Stage

It is a functional solution to a problem. A stage is returned from the `showCustomerDialog` function so that a reference to it can be stored by an external class which may wish to do something, such as hide the stage based on a button click in the main window, at a later time.  An alternate, object-oriented solution could encapsulate the functionality and stage reference inside a CustomerDialog object or have a CustomerDialog extend Stage.  A full example for an object-oriented interface to a custom dialog encapsulating FXML, controller and model data is beyond the scope of this answer, but may make a worthwhile blog post for anybody inclined to create one.

---

**Additional information supplied by StackOverflow user named [@dzim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1281217/bgmf)**

*Example for Spring Boot Dependency Injection*

The question of how to do it "The Spring Boot Way", there was a discussion about JavaFX 2, which I anserwered in the attached permalink.
The approach is still valid and tested in March 2016, on Spring Boot v1.3.3.RELEASE:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36310391/1281217

---

Sometimes, you might want to pass results back to the caller, in which case you can check out the answer to the related question:

- [JavaFX FXML Parameter passing from Controller A to B and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173320/javafx-fxml-parameter-passing-from-controller-a-to-b-and-back/48217255#48217255)

Comment: FXMLLoader constructors only take URLs as parameters.. what's the correct way to instantiate the FXMLLoader?

Comment: Updated answer to discuss FXMLLoader instantiation.

Comment: the event bus website alluded to states, "Update 3/2013: The EventBus has gone stale..."

Comment: The DataFX Controller Frameworks provides some injection support for FXML controllers: http://www.guigarage.com/2013/12/datafx-controller-framework-preview/

Comment: In my code, when I call my "controller.initData(customer);", controller is null. Any idea why that would be? Edit- I should add that I am calling this code from another controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, on first method, why do you return `Stage`? The method can be void as well because you already giving the command `show();` just before `return stage;`. How do you plan usage by returning the Stage?

Comment: Added additional Q&A section to answer to address the further questions of @Anarkie

Comment: Thanks for moving my Comment - i'm relativly new on answering questions on StackOverlow and was not sure, of how to do i appropriatly. Will keep this in mind for the next time. Cheers, Daniel

Comment: I have an example of integrating JavaFX with Spring at https://github.com/james-d/SpringFXExample. I'm not sure how useful it is in this context, as I made a facade to `FXMLLoader` (I just don't like the `FXMLLoader` API: "Be careful not to use the static load function", etc etc.), and I also played with things like letting node classes be Spring-managed beans and declared with elements, giving access to the `hostServices` object as a Spring bean, etc. Some of that might obfuscate the general idea to some degree.

Comment: for godshake is there anything simple for doing this tiny work in JavaFx? its a very common feature to pass data in constructor and javafx requires this hell of things all together just to send one name or one value?

Comment: The first example link is not bringing anywhere!

Comment: Yes, looks like the example was removed.  I replaced the link with a [link to the archived example content in the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160612045146/http://ed4becky.net/homepage/javafx-from-the-trenches-singleton-controllers/).

Comment: This way worked for me, but I found (like everyone else) that this does not load the data in the `initialize` method. I created a workaround that worked that allowed me to load the data in the `initialize` method. I used [`TimeLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html). I then set my `ListView` after a 1 second delay. You may have to adjust your delay depending on how long it takes your `Stage` to load.

Comment: so if we set the controller class into the fxml loader as shown , we won't be able to set also the fx:controller attribute? So we cannot put onAction attribute in the fxml file and create an listener for a button let's say? Did i get it wrong?

Comment: @Panagiss "So we cannot put onAction attribute in the fxml file and create an listener for a button let's say?"  This is wrong.  You should ask a new question.

Comment: @jewelsea Yea you are right, i'm wrong here but i had this false thought cause my IDE when setting the controller that way as shown here and NOT inside the FXML file, i was getting red the ```onAction``` attribute like it was an error. But on runtime it was everything OK and the listener was working as expected. So yeah you right

Comment: What would I do if the Controller contains fields declared `final`? I need to instantiate them in the constructor, not by calling the Controller's setter methods.

Comment: Don’t make the fields you need to set final, or, better yet, place them In an external class and construct that in your setter or pass it to your setter from the caller.  Generally, defining and using simple [immutable objects](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29) where you can is a good design pattern for this and other uses.

Answer (score 18):

> I realize this is a very old post and has some great answers already,
>   but I wanted to make a simple MCVE to demonstrate one such approach and allow new coders a way to quickly see the concept in action.

In this example, we will use 5 files:

1. **Main.java** - Simply used to start the application and call the first controller.
2. **Controller1.java** - The controller for the first FXML layout.
3. **Controller2.java** - The controller for the second FXML layout.
4. **Layout1.fxml** - The FXML layout for the first scene.
5. **Layout2.fxml** - The FXML layout for the second scene.

*All files are listed in their entirety at the bottom of this post.*

**The Goal:** To demonstrate passing values from `Controller1` to `Controller2` and vice versa.

**The Program Flow:**

- The first scene contains a `TextField`, a `Button`, and a `Label`. When the `Button` is clicked, the second window is loaded and displayed, including the text entered in the `TextField`.
- Within the second scene, there is also a `TextField`, a `Button`, and a `Label`. The `Label` will display the text entered in the `TextField` on the first scene.
- Upon entering text in the second scene's `TextField` and clicking its `Button`, the first scene's `Label` is updated to show the entered text.

This is a very simple demonstration and could surely stand for some improvement, but should make the concept very clear.

The code itself is also commented with some details of what is happening and how.

> **THE CODE**

**Main.java:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Create the first controller, which loads Layout1.fxml within its own constructor
        Controller1 controller1 = new Controller1();

        // Show the new stage
        controller1.showStage();

    }
}
```

**Controller1.java:**

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller1 {

    // Holds this controller's Stage
    private final Stage thisStage;

    // Define the nodes from the Layout1.fxml file. This allows them to be referenced within the controller
    @FXML
    private TextField txtToSecondController;
    @FXML
    private Button btnOpenLayout2;
    @FXML
    private Label lblFromController2;

    public Controller1() {

        // Create the new stage
        thisStage = new Stage();

        // Load the FXML file
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Layout1.fxml"));

            // Set this class as the controller
            loader.setController(this);

            // Load the scene
            thisStage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));

            // Setup the window/stage
            thisStage.setTitle("Passing Controllers Example - Layout1");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the stage that was loaded in the constructor
     */
    public void showStage() {
        thisStage.showAndWait();
    }

    /**
     * The initialize() method allows you set setup your scene, adding actions, configuring nodes, etc.
     */
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        // Add an action for the "Open Layout2" button
        btnOpenLayout2.setOnAction(event -> openLayout2());
    }

    /**
     * Performs the action of loading and showing Layout2
     */
    private void openLayout2() {

        // Create the second controller, which loads its own FXML file. We pass a reference to this controller
        // using the keyword [this]; that allows the second controller to access the methods contained in here.
        Controller2 controller2 = new Controller2(this);

        // Show the new stage/window
        controller2.showStage();

    }

    /**
     * Returns the text entered into txtToSecondController. This allows other controllers/classes to view that data.
     */
    public String getEnteredText() {
        return txtToSecondController.getText();
    }

    /**
     * Allows other controllers to set the text of this layout's Label
     */
    public void setTextFromController2(String text) {
        lblFromController2.setText(text);
    }
}
```

**Controller2.java:**

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller2 {

    // Holds this controller's Stage
    private Stage thisStage;

    // Will hold a reference to the first controller, allowing us to access the methods found there.
    private final Controller1 controller1;

    // Add references to the controls in Layout2.fxml
    @FXML
    private Label lblFromController1;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtToFirstController;
    @FXML
    private Button btnSetLayout1Text;

    public Controller2(Controller1 controller1) {
        // We received the first controller, now let's make it usable throughout this controller.
        this.controller1 = controller1;

        // Create the new stage
        thisStage = new Stage();

        // Load the FXML file
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Layout2.fxml"));

            // Set this class as the controller
            loader.setController(this);

            // Load the scene
            thisStage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));

            // Setup the window/stage
            thisStage.setTitle("Passing Controllers Example - Layout2");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the stage that was loaded in the constructor
     */
    public void showStage() {
        thisStage.showAndWait();
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        // Set the label to whatever the text entered on Layout1 is
        lblFromController1.setText(controller1.getEnteredText());

        // Set the action for the button
        btnSetLayout1Text.setOnAction(event -> setTextOnLayout1());
    }

    /**
     * Calls the "setTextFromController2()" method on the first controller to update its Label
     */
    private void setTextOnLayout1() {
        controller1.setTextFromController2(txtToFirstController.getText());
    }

}
```

**Layout1.fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0">
        <padding>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0"/>
        </padding>
        <Label style="-fx-font-weight: bold;" text="This is Layout1!"/>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="10.0">
            <Label text="Enter Text:"/>
            <TextField fx:id="txtToSecondController"/>
            <Button fx:id="btnOpenLayout2" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open Layout2"/>
        </HBox>
        <VBox alignment="CENTER">
            <Label text="Text From Controller2:"/>
            <Label fx:id="lblFromController2" text="Nothing Yet!"/>
        </VBox>
    </VBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Layout2.fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0">
        <padding>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0"/>
        </padding>
        <Label style="-fx-font-weight: bold;" text="Welcome to Layout 2!"/>
        <VBox alignment="CENTER">
            <Label text="Text From Controller1:"/>
            <Label fx:id="lblFromController1" text="Nothing Yet!"/>
        </VBox>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" spacing="10.0">
            <Label text="Enter Text:"/>
            <TextField fx:id="txtToFirstController"/>
            <Button fx:id="btnSetLayout1Text" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Set Text on Layout1"/>
        </HBox>
    </VBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the controller in the FXML file?
Beause removing the line: `loader.setController(this)` and adding the controller in the FXML file crashes the application

Comment: Not if the FXML is loaded from within the controller itself. If you load the FXML from the Main class, for example, you can define the controller in the FXML file and get a reference to it using `loader.getController()`

Comment: Finally i managed to find a solution, great example. I implemented it into my project and now I'm trying to make both windows open simultaneously and make first of them modal. Unfortunately only one opens. Could anyone help with it?

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example for passing parameters to a fxml document through namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/null" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <BorderPane>
        <center>
            <Label text="$labelText"/>
        </center>
    </BorderPane>
</VBox>
```

Define value `External Text` for namespace variable `labelText`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class NamespaceParameterExampleApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        final FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("namespace-parameter-example.fxml"));

        fxmlLoader.getNamespace()
                  .put("labelText", "External Text");

        final Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Namespace Parameter Example");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that some keys are used internally: e.g. `FXMLLoader.CONTROLLER_KEYWORD`, `FXMLLoader.LOCATION_KEY`, `FXMLLoader.RESOURCES_KEY` and any string used as value for the `fx:id` attribute.

Comment: Thank for this, my other scene is just a container that shows the text previously shown on my main scene. Now I can have one fxml that I can reuse in multiple places by initialiszing content via Namepace variables. I didnt' have to create any new methods or alter my constructor or initalisers - just addd variable in my FXML and add one line into my fxmloader code in the main controller.

Answer (score 7):

javafx.scene.Node class has a pair of methods 
setUserData(Object)
 and 
Object getUserData()

Which you could use to add your info to the Node.

So, you can call page.setUserData(info);

And controller can check, if info is set. Also, you could use ObjectProperty for back-forward data transfering, if needed.

Observe a documentation here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html
Before the phrase "In the first version, the handleButtonAction() is tagged with @FXML to allow markup defined in the controller's document to invoke it. In the second example, the button field is annotated to allow the loader to set its value. The initialize() method is similarly annotated."

So, you need to associate a controller with a node, and set a user data to the node.

Comment: Stage.getScene() -> Scene.getRoot() -> recursive search with Parent.getChildrenUnmodifiable(). This is very dirty way. If somebody could suggest smth better - that will be great.

Comment: It seems Stage.getScene().getRoot() is the correct way! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**This WORKS ..**

**Remember first time you print the passing value you will get null,
You can use it after your windows loaded , same for everything you want to code for any other component.**

> First Controller

```java
try {
    Stage st = new Stage();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/inty360/free/form/MainOnline.fxml"));

    Parent sceneMain = loader.load();

    MainOnlineController controller = loader.<MainOnlineController>getController();
    controller.initVariable(99L);

    Scene scene = new Scene(sceneMain);
    st.setScene(scene);
    st.setMaximized(true);
    st.setTitle("My App");
    st.show();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

> Another Controller

```java
public void initVariable(Long id_usuario){
    this.id_usuario = id_usuario;
    label_usuario_nombre.setText(id_usuario.toString());
}
```

Comment: This work when you pass parameter from first controller to second but how to pass parameter from second to first controller,i mean after first.fxml was loaded.

Comment: @XlintXms see the related question [JavaFX FXML Parameter passing from Controller A to B and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173320/javafx-fxml-parameter-passing-from-controller-a-to-b-and-back/48217255#48217255), which addresses your additional question.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create one Context Class.

```
public class Context {
    private final static Context instance = new Context();
    public static Context getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private Connection con;
    public void setConnection(Connection con)
    {
        this.con=con;
    }
    public Connection getConnection() {
        return con;
    }

    private TabRoughController tabRough;
    public void setTabRough(TabRoughController tabRough) {
        this.tabRough=tabRough;
    }

    public TabRoughController getTabRough() {
        return tabRough;
    }
}
```

You have to just set instance of controller in initialization using

```
Context.getInstance().setTabRough(this);
```

and you can use it from your whole application just using

```
TabRoughController cont=Context.getInstance().getTabRough();
```

Now you can pass parameter to any controller from whole application.

Comment: We use this approach and it works great. I like that I have access to data inside the constructor or in the initialize method and I don't have to set the data in the controller after it's constructed

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.
You need to add in the first controller:

```java
YourController controller = loader.getController();     
controller.setclient(client);
```

Then in the second one declare a client, then at the bottom of your controller:

```java
public void setclien(Client c) {
    this.client = c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for using a controller injected by Guice.

```
/**
 * Loads a FXML file and injects its controller from the given Guice {@code Provider}
 */
public abstract class GuiceFxmlLoader {

   public GuiceFxmlLoader(Stage stage, Provider<?> provider) {
      mStage = Objects.requireNonNull(stage);
      mProvider = Objects.requireNonNull(provider);
   }

   /**
    * @return the FXML file name
    */
   public abstract String getFileName();

   /**
    * Load FXML, set its controller with given {@code Provider}, and add it to {@code Stage}.
    */
   public void loadView() {
      try {
         FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(getFileName()));
         loader.setControllerFactory(p -> mProvider.get());
         Node view = loader.load();
         setViewInStage(view);
      }
      catch (IOException ex) {
         LOGGER.error("Failed to load FXML: " + getFileName(), ex);
      }
   }

   private void setViewInStage(Node view) {
      BorderPane pane = (BorderPane)mStage.getScene().getRoot();
      pane.setCenter(view);
   }

   private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(GuiceFxmlLoader.class);

   private final Stage mStage;
   private final Provider<?> mProvider;
}
```

Here is a concrete implementation of the loader:

```
public class ConcreteViewLoader extends GuiceFxmlLoader {

   @Inject
   public ConcreteViewLoader(Stage stage, Provider<MyController> provider) {
      super(stage, provider);
   }

   @Override
   public String getFileName() {
      return "my_view.fxml";
   }
}
```

Note this example loads the view into the center of a BoarderPane that is the root of the Scene in the Stage. This is irrelevant to the example (implementation detail of my specific use case) but decided to leave it in as some may find it useful.

Answer (score -3):

You can decide to use a public observable list to store public data, or just create a public setter method to store data and retrieve from the corresponding controller

Answer (score -4):

Why answer a 6 year old question ?
One the most fundamental concepts working with any programming language is how to navigate from one (window, form or page) to another. Also while doing this navigation the developer often wants to pass data from one (window, form or page) and display or use the data passed
While most of the answers here provide good to excellent examples how to accomplish this we thought we would kick it up a notch or two or three
We said three because we will navigate between three (window, form or page) and use the concept of static variables to pass data around the (window, form or page)
We will also include some decision making code while we navigate

```java
public class Start extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // This is MAIN Class which runs first
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("start.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);// This sets the value for all stages
        stage.setTitle("Start Page"); 
        stage.show();
        stage.sizeToScene();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    } 
}
```

Start Controller

```
public class startController implements Initializable {

@FXML Pane startPane,pageonePane;
@FXML Button btnPageOne;
@FXML TextField txtStartValue;
public Stage stage;
public static int intSETonStartController;
String strSETonStartController;

@FXML
private void toPageOne() throws IOException{

    strSETonStartController = txtStartValue.getText().trim();


        // yourString != null && yourString.trim().length() > 0
        // int L = testText.length();
        // if(L == 0){
        // System.out.println("LENGTH IS "+L);
        // return;
        // }
        /* if (testText.matches("[1-2]") && !testText.matches("^\\s*$")) 
           Second Match is regex for White Space NOT TESTED !
        */

        String testText = txtStartValue.getText().trim();
        // NOTICE IF YOU REMOVE THE * CHARACTER FROM "[1-2]*"
        // NO NEED TO CHECK LENGTH it also permited 12 or 11 as valid entry 
        // =================================================================
        if (testText.matches("[1-2]")) {
            intSETonStartController = Integer.parseInt(strSETonStartController);
        }else{
            txtStartValue.setText("Enter 1 OR 2");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("You Entered = "+intSETonStartController);
        stage = (Stage)startPane.getScene().getWindow();// pane you are ON
        pageonePane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("pageone.fxml"));// pane you are GOING TO
        Scene scene = new Scene(pageonePane);// pane you are GOING TO
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Page One"); 
        stage.show();
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.centerOnScreen();  
}

private void doGET(){
    // Why this testing ?
    // strSENTbackFROMPageoneController is null because it is set on Pageone
    // =====================================================================
    txtStartValue.setText(strSENTbackFROMPageoneController);
    if(intSETonStartController == 1){
      txtStartValue.setText(str);  
    }
    System.out.println("== doGET WAS RUN ==");
    if(txtStartValue.getText() == null){
       txtStartValue.setText("");   
    }
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // This Method runs every time startController is LOADED
     doGET();
}    
}
```

Page One Controller

```
public class PageoneController implements Initializable {

@FXML Pane startPane,pageonePane,pagetwoPane;
@FXML Button btnOne,btnTwo;
@FXML TextField txtPageOneValue;
public static String strSENTbackFROMPageoneController;
public Stage stage;

    @FXML
private void onBTNONE() throws IOException{

        stage = (Stage)pageonePane.getScene().getWindow();// pane you are ON
        pagetwoPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("pagetwo.fxml"));// pane you are GOING TO
        Scene scene = new Scene(pagetwoPane);// pane you are GOING TO
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Page Two"); 
        stage.show();
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.centerOnScreen();
}

@FXML
private void onBTNTWO() throws IOException{
    if(intSETonStartController == 2){
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Alert");
        alert.setHeaderText("YES to change Text Sent Back");
        alert.setResizable(false);
        alert.setContentText("Select YES to send 'Alert YES Pressed' Text Back\n"
                + "\nSelect CANCEL send no Text Back\r");// NOTE this is a Carriage return\r
        ButtonType buttonTypeYes = new ButtonType("YES");
        ButtonType buttonTypeCancel = new ButtonType("CANCEL", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);

        alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonTypeYes, buttonTypeCancel);

        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        if (result.get() == buttonTypeYes){
            txtPageOneValue.setText("Alert YES Pressed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("canceled");
            txtPageOneValue.setText("");
            onBack();// Optional
        }
    }
}

@FXML
private void onBack() throws IOException{

    strSENTbackFROMPageoneController = txtPageOneValue.getText();
    System.out.println("Text Returned = "+strSENTbackFROMPageoneController);
    stage = (Stage)pageonePane.getScene().getWindow();
    startPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("start.fxml")); 
    Scene scene = new Scene(startPane);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Start Page"); 
    stage.show();
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.centerOnScreen(); 
}

private void doTEST(){
    String fromSTART = String.valueOf(intSETonStartController);
    txtPageOneValue.setText("SENT  "+fromSTART);
    if(intSETonStartController == 1){
       btnOne.setVisible(true);
       btnTwo.setVisible(false);
       System.out.println("INTEGER Value Entered = "+intSETonStartController);  
    }else{
       btnOne.setVisible(false);
       btnTwo.setVisible(true);
       System.out.println("INTEGER Value Entered = "+intSETonStartController); 
    }  
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    doTEST();
}    

}
```

Page Two Controller

```
public class PagetwoController implements Initializable {

@FXML Pane startPane,pagetwoPane;
public Stage stage;
public static String str;

@FXML
private void toStart() throws IOException{

    str = "You ON Page Two";
    stage = (Stage)pagetwoPane.getScene().getWindow();// pane you are ON
    startPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("start.fxml"));// pane you are GOING TO
    Scene scene = new Scene(startPane);// pane you are GOING TO
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Start Page"); 
    stage.show();
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.centerOnScreen();  
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

}    

}
```

Below are all the FXML files

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="pagetwoPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="atwopage.PagetwoController">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="227.0" layoutY="62.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#toStart" text="To Start Page">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="startPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="atwopage.startController">
   <children>
      <Label focusTraversable="false" layoutX="115.0" layoutY="47.0" text="This is the Start Pane">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="btnPageOne" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="137.0" layoutY="100.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#toPageOne" text="To Page One">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Label focusTraversable="false" layoutX="26.0" layoutY="150.0" text="Enter 1 OR 2">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="txtStartValue" layoutX="137.0" layoutY="148.0" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="pageonePane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="atwopage.PageoneController">
   <children>
      <Label focusTraversable="false" layoutX="111.0" layoutY="35.0" text="This is Page One Pane">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button focusTraversable="false" layoutX="167.0" layoutY="97.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onBack" text="BACK">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font></Button>
      <Button fx:id="btnOne" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="19.0" layoutY="97.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onBTNONE" text="Button One" visible="false">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="btnTwo" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="267.0" layoutY="97.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onBTNTWO" text="Button Two">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Label focusTraversable="false" layoutX="19.0" layoutY="152.0" text="Send Anything BACK">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="txtPageOneValue" layoutX="195.0" layoutY="150.0" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but posting a hundred lines of code without any explanation of what it does or why you do it the way you do it, is not a very good answer. Plus, the code you posted is very poorly organized and difficult to follow.

Comment: There is no need to be rude to the asking person. We are all here to learn